# mosquitto_sub and Tuya TS0601 TRV

Tags: mqtt, tuya

Is it possible to send settings to a TS0601 TRV from MQTT?

For example:

```
# mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t Home/Bed3/Radiator/set/force -m "open" -d
Client mosqpub|19143-mini31 sending CONNECT
Client mosqpub|19143-mini31 received CONNACK (0)
Client mosqpub|19143-mini31 sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m1, 'Home/Bed3/Radiator/set/force', ... (4 bytes))
Client mosqpub|19143-mini31 sending DISCONNECT
```

but nothing happens.

I can see my sent messages appearing in

```
# mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t Home/Bed3/Radiator/# -v
```

Comment: This is a question about how a specific bit of hardware works, not really a software question. As such it's probably off topic for here. It would likely be fine on https://iot.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also when/if you repost please include a LOT more detail about the stack you are using, because the device you mention is Zigbee, so no direct access to MQTT